# Detect number of pages in custom class

Tags: page-numbering, document-classes, documentclass-writing

How can I make a conditional in my custom documentclass (based on article) for when the document is only one page long?

I need this because when it is only one page, I don't want to put the page number in the footer (but if there is multiple pages, I *do* want the page number on the first page—so it's not simply a matter of giving the first page a numberless footer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option, using a combination of [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) and [`lastpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
\usepackage{refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount
\makeatletter
\let\oldenddocument\enddocument
\renewcommand{\enddocument}{%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=1\pagestyle{empty}\fi%
  \oldenddocument
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}​
```

The idea is to check the value of the last page's number in an expandable form using `\getpagerefnumber` of the `LastPage` label (offered by `lastpage`). I doubt whether [`pageslts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) is required here.

I've used `\pagestyle{empty}`, but you could change this to whatever page style you want to. For example, if you're using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and you want to define a footer-less page style that still contains a header.

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is just for dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style. Here's a two-page output (the above MWE):

[image]

Here's a one-page output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How would I change the conditional to **not**, so that it only sets `\fancyfoot[R]{\small \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}` when its not 1? I tried `!=` and that isn't it.

Comment: @Mk12: I would set the default have the footer `\fancyfoot[R]{\small \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}` and then keep my original conditional to remove it for the first page. `\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=1\fancyfoot{}\fi`. In general, for `!=` conditioning, you could use `\ifnum<num1>=<num2>\else<!= clause>\fi`. Also see the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) for more on conditional statements.